# How to debug in this simple Python homework?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need a little bit of help with a homework problem for school using python.  The prompt is pretty simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
'''
rem(A,B) returns the list 
              [A[0]%B[0], A[1]%B[1], ...]  etc

>>> rem( (10,20,30), (7,8,9) )
[3, 4, 3]
>>> X = [ i for i in range(10,18) ] 
>>> Y = [ j+3 for j in range(8) ]
>>> rem(X,Y)+["?"]
[1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 7, 7, '?']
>>> rem( [5,3], [3,2] )
[2, 1]
>>> rem( [10,9], [5,4] )
[0, 1]
'''
```

I have created this snippet of code which sort of works but not quite:

```
def rem(A,B):
    return [A[0] % b for b in B]
```

Right now the definition is working, but only for the first value in each sequence.  I think this is due to the `A[0]` - I need some way to make it do `A[x+1]`, but I'm not sure.  Also I'm pretty sure that I have to use `range()` somewhere in the definition as well.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pair up each element of `A` with its corresponding element in `B`, and then mod them.

```
[x % y for (x, y) in zip(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750028/please-help-me-simple-python-homework/7750050#7750050) is correct and the most pythonic, this is the more basic way:

```
def rem(a,b):
    l = []
    for x in range(len(a)):
         l.append(a[x]%b[x])
    return l
```

See comments too!

Comment: The asker is already familiar with LCs. My answer simply illustrates `zip()` and tuple unpacking during iteration, which are the last two concepts that were missing. And please don't write code that iterates over `range(len(...))`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you are right, he is familiar with them. Sorry. But why not `range(len())` is it not forward comaptible? Or why do you say? As I said, I think your answer is better, I just wanted to add another option.

Comment: Using `range(len(...))` requires multiple indexing operations to retrieve the objects, as opposed to `zip()` (or `itertools.izip()`) exposing the objects directly.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for the advice, I'll read up on it. I have seen this way of iterating so many times I assumed it was "correct" or efficient. Thanks again for the advice!